# Using regular expression with not function in css

Tags: css

There is a way to use regular expresssion in css not function like this:

```
*:not(.^col-) {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

i mean apply to elements except those has a class begining with "col-".
so how can i do this with css?

**Note:** the class attribute may content other class like `<a class="a-class b-class col-12">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use regular expressions with CSS. However, there are ways to select elements which attributes start/end/contain certain strings.

In this case, I believe you're trying to select all elements for which their `class` doesn't start with `col-`. You can use this:

```css
*:not([class ^= "col-"]) {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Note that `[class ^= "col-"]` will only match if the `class` attribute starts with `col-`, so `<element class="col-123 abc">` will match but `<element class="abc col-123">` will not.

Because of that, it's recommended to have a separate class which is the same for all elements. You can do it with JavaScript:

```js
// Note: This code isn't very efficient. Add the class manually whenever possible.
const tw = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
  acceptNode(elem) {
    if ([...elem.classList].some(c => c.startsWith("col-")))
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    else
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
  }
});
while (tw.nextNode()) {
  tw.currentNode.classList.add("col");
}
```

```css
.col {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc col-12">Test div</div>
<div class="abc">Another test div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
is it possible to add for exemple a "col" class to all elements that have a class containing "col-" using javascript?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's now edited with a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the class `.col` to things that you don't want to change then go to CSS and change your code.

```css
 *:not(.col) {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col" style="background-color: red;">This is example</div>
```

Comment: Why you edited my answer??

Comment: To improve it, of course. There is no need to say it's working, we can see that in the snippet. Don't worry; editing answers is a common procedure here on Stack Overflow. 

Comment: I am a beginner and want to earn more reputation, my answer went down and you came first that's why I got scared and asked. Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you. is it possible to add for exemple a "col" class to all elements that have a class containing "col-" using javascript?

Comment: I don't think so